# Convert json string to array format, that can be use to chart data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Actual data :

```
 var x =" [{ name: 'Chintan test', data: [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] }, 
{ name: 'Lara Black &White', data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] }, 
{ name: 'kamlesh ', data: [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] }, { name: 'Gopala lalalala', data: [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] }, 
{ name: 'Saurin Test ', data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] }]";
```

how to convert so i can get below result :

```
var y = [{ name: 'Chintan test', data: [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] }, 
{ name: 'Lara Black &White', data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] }, 
{ name: 'kamlesh ', data: [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] }, { name: 'Gopala lalalala', data: [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] }, 
{ name: 'Saurin Test ', data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] }]
```

What I had Done :

try 1 :

```
y=x.substring(1,x.length-1);  // not helpfull
```

try 2 :

```
y = JSON.parse(x);  //  SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 5 of the JSON data
```

Comment: That is not even valid JSON

Comment: That's not valid JSON, hence why it can't be parsed by `JSON.parse`.

Comment: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @meskobalazs I have seen this mistake many times on the forum.

Comment: you can only save an object with json - when you want to use the array in json format, you could just do `x = { data: y }` - this would be valid as json since you can store an array in an attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string is not valid JSON (you can check it here http://jsonlint.com/), so in order to parse it you first need to transform it in a valid JSON.

To make it a valid JSON the attribute names should be encapsulated by double quotes (name: => "name":) and the same goes for the strings ('Chintan test' => "Chintan test"). You can do this with a few string replace:

```
var x =" [{ name: 'Chintan test', data: [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] }, { name: 'Lara Black &White', data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] }, { name: 'kamlesh ', data: [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] }, { name:'Gopala lalalala', data: [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] }, { name: 'Saurin Test ', data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] }]";

x = x.replace(/data:/g, '"data":'); //name attribute data to "data"
x = x.replace(/name:/g, '"name":'); //name attribute name to "name"
x = x.replace(/:\s*'(.+?)'/g, ':"$1"'); // :'string' to :"string"

var y = JSON.parse(x);
```

Note that the string inside x should not contain new lines.

The jsfiddle working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jx3opp8g/

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid JSON mostly because JSON requires that the property names be surrounded by quotes.  Once you add quotes around the property names, then it looks like it should be parse able.